# Parsing recursive json, from markdown AST

Tags: javascript, recursion, github-flavored-markdown

Recursive functions are not my forté, and im pretty sure thats what is needed here.

I have a nested json object, which represents a nested checklist
It is autogenerated from markdown using [mdast-util-gfm-task-list-item](https://github.com/syntax-tree/mdast-util-gfm-task-list-item)

```markdown
* AAA
    * BBB
* CCC
    * [x] DDD
        * [ ] EEE
        * FFF
```

```json
    {
    "type": "root",
    "children": [
        {
            "type": "list",
            "ordered": false,
            "start": null,
            "spread": false,
            "children": [
                {
                    "type": "listItem",
                    "spread": false,
                    "checked": null,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "type": "paragraph",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "value": "AAA"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "list",
                            "ordered": false,
                            "start": null,
                            "spread": false,
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "type": "listItem",
                                    "spread": false,
                                    "checked": null,
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "paragraph",
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "text",
                                                    "value": "BBB"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "listItem",
                    "spread": false,
                    "checked": null,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "type": "paragraph",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "value": "CCC"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "list",
                            "ordered": false,
                            "start": null,
                            "spread": false,
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "type": "listItem",
                                    "spread": false,
                                    "checked": null,
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "paragraph",
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "text",
                                                    "value": "DDD"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "list",
                                            "ordered": false,
                                            "start": null,
                                            "spread": false,
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "listItem",
                                                    "spread": false,
                                                    "checked": null,
                                                    "children": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "paragraph",
                                                            "children": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "type": "text",
                                                                    "value": "EEE"
                                                                }
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "type": "listItem",
                                                    "spread": false,
                                                    "checked": null,
                                                    "children": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "paragraph",
                                                            "children": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "type": "text",
                                                                    "value": "FFF"
                                                                }
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to manipulate it to be in the following, more consise format:

```json
{
    "type" : "list",
    "data" : {
        "style" : "unordered",
        "items" : [
            {
              "content": "AAA",
              "checked" : null
              "items": [
                {
                  "content": "BBB",
                  "checked" : null
                  "items": []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "content": "CCC",
              "checked" : null
              "items": [
                {
                  "content": "DDD",
                  "checked": true,
                  "items": [
                      {
                        "content": "EEE",
                        "checked": false,
                        "items": []
                      },
                      {
                        "content": "FFF",
                        "checked": null,
                         "items": []
                      }
                   ]
                },
              ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated - I have been banging my head against the wall for a couple of hours now.

Comment: Why does `EEE` get `checked: false` and `FFF` get `checked: null` if they have identical input structures?  And why does `DDD` get `checked: true` if the input had `checked: null`?

Comment: Also, why do we get `{style: unordered}` for the root but not for other lists such as `DDD`?

Comment: @ScottSauyet This is the result of the markdown-AST format. The problem is that lists in markdown are a bit of a mess, not well defined, and very flexible. The checkbox addition, is something github added for github-flavoured-markdown, not part of the original format. So representing them "cleanly" is challenging. You can technically have a valid nested list that has some ordered and unordered properties, and also some checked, and some not checked, and some without checkboxes. EG : `null | true | false`

Comment: I'm looking at your requested output, not the input.

Comment: For instance the input structures for `EEE` and `FFF` are identical, but your requested outputs are different.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - Yep, you are right sorry, that looks like my mistake, as I manually wrote the output json, (as i couldnt generate it) it looks like i mistakenly changed the state of the checkboxes on the outputs, sorry. Luckily the proposed solutions managed to work around my oversight. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I am pretty close here but haven't been able to finish it off:

```
function transform(data) {
  const {type} = data;
  if (type === "root") {
    return transform(data.children[0]);
  } else if (type === "list") {
    return {
      type,
      data: {
        style: data.ordered ? "ordered" : "unordered",
        items: data.children.map(child => transform(child))
      }
    }
  } else if (type === "listItem") {
    return {
      type,
      checked: data.checked,
      content: data.children[0].children[0].value,
      items: data.children.filter(child => child.type === "list").map(child => transform(child))
    }
  }
  return data;
}

// Pass your data in here as fromData
const toData = transform(fromData);

// toData would then be the new format
```

Answer (score 0):

The version I had been working on is similar to what you figured out yourself, but it's done in a different coding style, and it removes one layer of array from `/root/data/items`, which wasn't there in your requested output and doesn't make much sense.

```js
const convert = ({type, children, ordered, checked}) => 
  type == 'root'
    ? {
        type: 'list', 
        data: {style: ordered ? 'ordered' : 'unordered', items: convert (children [0])}
      }
  : type == 'list'
    ? children .map (convert)
  : type == 'listItem'
    ? {
        content: children [0] .children [0] .value, 
        checked: checked, 
        items: children [1] ? convert (children [1]) : []
      }
  : {error: `unknown type: '${type}'`}

const ast = {type: "root", children: [{type: "list", ordered: false, start: null, spread: false, children: [{type: "listItem", spread: false, checked: null, children: [{type: "paragraph", children: [{type: "text", value: "AAA"}]}, {type: "list", ordered: false, start: null, spread: false, children: [{type: "listItem", spread: false, checked: null, children: [{type: "paragraph", children: [{type: "text", value: "BBB"}]}]}]}]}, {type: "listItem", spread: false, checked: null, children: [{type: "paragraph", children: [{type: "text", value: "CCC"}]}, {type: "list", ordered: false, start: null, spread: false, children: [{type: "listItem", spread: false, checked: true, children: [{type: "paragraph", children: [{type: "text", value: "DDD"}]}, {type: "list", ordered: false, start: null, spread: false, children: [{type: "listItem", spread: false, checked: false, children: [{type: "paragraph", children: [{type: "text", value: "EEE"}]}]}, {type: "listItem", spread: false, checked: null, children: [{type: "paragraph", children: [{type: "text", value: "FFF"}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}

console .log (convert (ast))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I also changed the input to represent `checked: true` for `DDD` and `checked: false` for `EEE` to match your sample markup.  The initial AST had `null` for both of those.  I'm assuming that `null` is meant for "no checkbox here" and `true` and `false` would be used if there is one checked or unchecked.  If that's not the case, then it might take a bit of fiddling.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jimTheDev

I also recived some assistance on another forum, and both answers were useful.
In the end, I have sucssfully produced the following function, which works almost perfectly for my use case.

```js
let ast_to_ejs = (input) => {
    const { type, children } = input;
    if (type === "root") {
      const data = {};
      data.style = input.ordered ? 'ordered' : 'unordered';
      data.items = children.map(ast_to_ejs);
      return { type: 'list', data };
  
    } else if (type === 'list') {
       return children.map(ast_to_ejs);
  
    } else if (type === 'listItem') {
      const checked = input.checked;
      const content = children[0].children[0].value;
       const items = children[1] ? ast_to_ejs(children[1]) : [];
       return { content, checked, items };
     }
};
```